# Cannot open dplay.lib error in VS2015

Tags: visual-studio, directx

While migrating project from Visual Studio 2006 to 2015 we get an LINKING

> ERROR: Error  LNK1104 cannot open file 'dplay.lib'    .

How to resolve this error?

Answer (score 0):

`dplay.lib` is "DirectPlay", which has been [deprecated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DirectPlay), and is no longer part of recent Windows deployments.

> DirectPlay will be supported in DirectX DLLs for the lifetime of Microsoft Windows XP, but from the autumn of 2007[2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Games_for_Windows_%E2%80%93_Live) the headers and libraries — vital components if developers wanted to develop new programs that utilize the technology — were absent from the DirectX SDK.

Its successor, [Games for Windows - Live](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Games_for_Windows_%E2%80%93_Live), is based on the XBox Live service, and it's likely you will need to modify your code to support it. There are other networking service APIs, such as [Steamworks](https://partner.steamgames.com/), although again, you will need to modify your code to support them.

Also, there was no [Visual Studio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio#History) 2006 version.